# Custom Data Binding using MVC 4 Razor Engine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am beginning out using the .NET MVC 4 Framework and am trying to figure out how to customize the data binding that Razor uses for forms. For example, I have been taught in class to use something like `@Html.TextBoxFor(be => be.Title)` to bind an input text box to a Model.Title property. But what if I want to send a custom control across the same binding Model?

For example, I am creating a blogging CMS and have a custom "tagging" control for tagging blog posts. I want to bind a string array of tags to a `List<String>()` object in my backend. How can I go about making this work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

For binding to a List you don't need a custom model binder, simply use the syntax in your razor view:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.SomeCollectionProperty.Count; ++i)
 {
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeCollectionProperty[i])
 }
```

That said, if you *do* need to create a custom model binder for a more complex scenario, you simply need to implement an [IModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) or override e.g. the `BindProperty` method of the [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and register it with the MVC framework.

In the first case, you register your custom binder in the `Application_Start` of your `global.asax` like so:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyFancyType), new MyFancyTypeModelBinder());
```

In the second case, you replace the default model binder like so:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new MyExtendedDefaultModelBinder();
```

In both of these cases, your model binder classes need to be thread-safe, since the same model binder instance will be used for all http requests.

As a third option, you can actually take full control of model binder construction by implementing an [IModelBinderProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinderprovider%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and registering it like so:

```
ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(new MyModelBinderProvider());
```

The final option that I am aware of is to use the [ModelBinderAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbinderattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), like so

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomModelBinder))]
public class MyModelClass
{
    public class MyCustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In the above example, the model binder is actually nested inside the model class, but it can be defined separately as well.

I tend to prefer to implement `IModelBinder` and register it in the model binders dictionary - as that allows me easily to reuse the same type across multiple models with one simple registration.  In the rare event that I need to completely customize model binding for a particular model, I will use the last approach.

Comment: But what if I am starting with a new Object and I want to Add to the List, meaning it starts out with Count = 0. As far as I'm concerned, the code you posted would work for editing the data

Comment: Then you can populate your initial list with string.Empty for however many items you want to allow. If you want to dynamically add items, you can append a new item to the list on the post action, or do it client side by creating new elements that follow the model binding naming convention.